# Javascript (Total Profit)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I'm working on the assignment below for my class and I'm confused because I'm not exactly sure if I should be using console.log for the user input. Not to mention, if my total variable is correct as well. Can someone please advise?

> A company has determined that its annual profit is typically 23 percent of total sales. Write a program called sales_prediction.js, that displays the profit based on the project amount of total sales for the year. Use a literal value of $2,500,000 for the projected total sales amount. Display the profit amount formatted to two decimal places.

This program will ask the user to input the annual profit for their company,
once the profit is input by the user, the system will multiply said dollar
amount by twenty-three percent.

```
//Ask user to input annual profit dollar amount
var annual = "What is this the total annual sales dollar amount?";

//Multiply the annual sales dollar amount by twenty-three percent
var total_sales = annual * 0.23;

//Display total sales for the year
console.log("The total sales for the year are $" +total_sales);
```

Comment: Clearly can't multiply a sentence by a number and get anything meaningful. This isn't a code writing or homework service

Comment: so are you saying that I should change var total_sales = numerical dollar amount * 0.23?

Comment: Well of course...isn't that fairly obvious? A pencil and paper might help here

Comment: LOL! I get what you're saying in reference to that, however, I guess where I'm lost is, wouldn't "annual" reference the dollar amount input by the user?

Comment: Well if that is the case you need to learn how to use user events in the dom and how to get values from input elements and do the calculation inside an event handler. What you currently have doesn't come close to doing any of that and this whole question is far too broad for this site

Comment: The assignement say **Use a literal value of $2,500,000 for the projected total sales** so you don't need to prompt the user. Just `var annual =  2500000;` will do. Then you calculate the profit like you did.

Comment: @LawrenceWilson I suspect that this question is going to be closed soon for "being to broad" or "homework related" (unfortunately Stack Overflow isn't a fun place to ask beginner questions, I'm sorry for that). I'd recommend to try to create (or find) a more specific question, like "How can I get user input in JavaScript?" Chances are that it will be easier to get a decent answer there.

Comment: @Tiddo nothing wrong with homework questions, or beginner questions so long as they conform to guidelines for proper questions outlined in [help] and include legitimate code that attempts to solve the actual problem. This is clearly one of those that is looking for a lot more direction than that

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was able to solve this question and my other homework question now that I was given some type of direction.

Answer (score 0):

var annual = prompt("What is this the total annual sales dollar amount?")

and of course you could alert("Your total dollar amount is $"+total_sales)

But also,  I doubt that would display it as 2 decimal places,  you'd have to work that out yourself.